# convert emoji to their hex code

Tags: php, converters, emoji

I'm trying to detect the emoji that I get through e.g. a POST (the source ist not necessary).

As an example I'm using this emoji: ✊ (I hope it's visible)

The code for it is `U+270A U+1F3FE` (I'm using http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html for the codes)

Now I converted the emoji with json_encode and I get: `\u270a\ud83c\udffe`

Here the only part that is equal is `270a`. `\ud83c\udffe` is not equal to `U+1F3FE`, not even if I add them together (`1B83A`)

How do I get from ✊ to `U+270A U+1F3FE` with e.g. php?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mb_convert_encoding` and convert from `UTF-8` to `UTF-32`. Then do some additional formatting:

```
// Strips leading zeros
// And returns str in UPPERCASE letters with a U+ prefix
function format($str) {
    $copy = false;
    $len = strlen($str);
    $res = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $ch = $str[$i];

        if (!$copy) {
            if ($ch != '0') {
                $copy = true;
            }
            // Prevent format("0") from returning ""
            else if (($i + 1) == $len) {
                $res = '0';
            }
        }

        if ($copy) {
            $res .= $ch;
        }
    }

    return 'U+'.strtoupper($res);
}

function convert_emoji($emoji) {
    // ✊ --> 0000270a0001f3fe
    $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $hex = bin2hex($emoji);

    // Split the UTF-32 hex representation into chunks
    $hex_len = strlen($hex) / 8;
    $chunks = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $hex_len; ++$i) {
        $tmp = substr($hex, $i * 8, 8);

        // Format each chunk
        $chunks[$i] = format($tmp);
    }

    // Convert chunks array back to a string
    return implode($chunks, ' ');
}

echo convert_emoji('✊'); // U+270A U+1F3FE
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple function, inspired by @d3L answer above

```
function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
   $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
   $unicode = strtoupper(preg_replace("/^[0]+/","U+",bin2hex($emoji)));
   return $unicode;
}
```

Exmaple

```
emoji_to_unicode("");//returns U+1F4B5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, consider the emoji a normal character.

```
$emoji = "✊";

$str = str_replace('"', "", json_encode($emoji, JSON_HEX_APOS));

$myInput = $str;

$myHexString = str_replace('\\u', '', $myInput);
$myBinString = hex2bin($myHexString);

print iconv("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", $myBinString);
```

Comment: I don't want to create a list with all emojis. If there is a code, how did someone else get to it?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I guess you'll need a library for that.

Comment: Well that is still not that what I wrote as a final question ... you just corrected the json_encode and printed it again.